# How can I sync all folders from an Exchange server (not just the Inbox)?

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-s-2, exchange

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S2 (Android 2.3.4) and have set up the native email app to synchronize with an MS Exchange 2007 server. The problem I am noticing is that I'm only notified for a new email if it is sent to my Inbox folder. I have to sync my other folders one-by-one.

Is there any sync all option?

Comment: Do you have server-side rules that move mail automatically to other folders? Reason I'm asking: usually every mail should end up in your inbox folder first.
There are two cases where this doesn't happen: a) server-side rules or b) client-side rules that are enforced while the Outlook client application is running and checking for mail.

Comment: No the emails in the MS outlook are directed through the rules to the coresponding server. So when I have a new email to a folder other than inbox I have to sync the specific folder. It is not efficient in case of big number of email folders.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the native Android Exchange Client doesn't support automatic sync of sub-folders, as you have seen you can go in to the folder and sync it manually but that isn't much use.
This hasn't been improved much in Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich. The sub folders now sync but it doesn't notify you of new messages in them which isn't really any better.

I would recommend using a 3rd Party client like Moxier or Touchdown. Both have trials so that you can test them first.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you've made any headway on this. I was searching for answers for this today and got it figured out. I've got a Galaxy S4, running 4.2.2 I had to open the native email app.

`Menu > Settings > Exchange Account with sub folders > More Settings > Folder Sync Settings`. From there I think it should be self explanatory.

Not sure what version of Android you're running by now, but thought I'd share.

Comment: using 4.2.1 I do not have the "more settings" menu. Any one has an idea of how I can get to the folder setting then?

Answer (score 1):

I am using galaxy S2 with android 4.0.4. I am getting alert for sub-folders. You go to email client and select sub-folders from the menu. After reaching the sub-folder, select menu button and you will find sync option. You can select as automatic push. It gives alert immediately.

Answer (score 0):

As Nuronv states,  in Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich, the sub folders are synchronized.  However, I have found in my case that only a partial list of sub-folders are synchronized.

I have server-side rules set up to sort all of my mail into very specific folders and the client is configured to save replies in the same folder with the email.  This allows me to maintain collections of emails and conversations with a specific client, vendor, or project.  I literally have hundreds of folders and sub-folders.

In my first experience synchronizing, it only caught 3 sub-folders on the 2nd level  (I have about 8), and in each of those folders, it found 3 in one folder that I have over 40, and 8 in another folder where I have about 15.  It does not seem aparent why this is happening.

I will take Nuronv's second suggestion and go check out Moxier or Touchdown.

Comment: UPDATE:  Neither Moxier or Touchdown seem to be a viable replacement.

After several months of testing and evaluating both products, neither of them have proven themselves to be a viable replacement.

The primary reason being, that neither of them integrate properly with the built-in contacts, calendar, or mail.  I have contacts in my phone, and want all of the contacts on my Exchange server, integrated.  Touchdown integrates, but the categories I have defined on Exchange, are disregarded and are replaced instead by "TouchDown Exchange".  That's useless.  All contacts in one group?  Seriously?

Comment: ...additionally, each of them have their own dedicated calendar.  I want an application that displays the calendar items, right along side the built-in Google calendar, so I can elect to show those events or not, and compare my business events, side-by-side, with my personal events.

The built-in Exchange ActiveSync does both of these things very well.  It just doesn't alert on new mail in sub-folders.  That's really the only thing I don't like about it.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a Note 8 and the sub folders that I use to organize my work emails were nowhere to be found. I went through every setting but no luck. I tried some of the other email apps that were recommended here and at other help sites. In the end, the only one that worked to show my sub folders was the Microsoft Outlook app. No settings to hunt for. It just worked. I was about to return my Note 8 before I found that this app solved my problem. Too bad Samsung can't fix there default app!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the default email app, just have to find the settings.

- Open your Samsung email app.
- Next to the Inbox, click on the 3 line menu bar. At the very top you will find a gear(Settings).
- Choose the account you are trying to sync all folders (Just click on the account) This will open the settings for this email account.
- Scroll halfway down to the Section 'Exchange ActiveSync Settings' then choose Folder Sync
- Be sure to hit the ^ on the Inbox to expand
- Choose the folders you wish to Sync.
- You will be cautioned on the amount of folders syncing as it will slow the sync process down.
- Re-sync your phone and you should see all your folders now.

Answer (score -1):

the best solution is to just replace the exchange server.
saves you a lot of headdaches.
You can try Zarafa, Zimbra, OpenChange, Communigate etc.
Or just Google Apps, which very nicely talks caldav and carddav and imap, instead of the propriatery mapi crap.

Comment: Replacing exchange server just to get your phone to sync subfolders is a really stupid idea - this is not a solution.