# ICS (Android 4.0.3), Samsung Galaxy S2, Exchange Email

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, email, exchange

My phone just updated to ICS (Android version 4.0.3). Before I was able to ACCESS all sub-folders in my microsoft exchange email account, now I can only see my inbox!

How do I fix this?  Does anyone know how to see the sub-folders when using ICS?  I was able to before my phone updated to ICS, now I cannot!

Is it because of my phone? I am using a Samsung Galaxy S2.

Comment: Sounds like a similar problem as [How can I sync all folders from an Exchange server (not just the Inbox)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17004) (same device, different version of Android).

Comment: Thanks for that eldarerathis.  I actually read through that but it doesn't deal with it.  That person can see the sub-folders but the mail in them is not updated.  ICS does not even SHOW me the subfolders!

Comment: Have you tried clearing the data or the cache for the app?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and I found a way of seeing the subfolders on my Galaxy.

On the PC, open your inbox and create a new subfolder (eg foo).

On your phone, open email and open your inbox. in Options, select 'Folders'.
You will see your Inbox with a small green arrow icon. Click the icon (not the Inbox title) and your folder list will expand.

Note that this only worked for me after I had created the extra dummy folder. Before I created the folder, I could see the green icon, but it would not expand the list of subfolders.

Comment: I had / have the same propblem, and after all the folders went, by creating a dummy folder it seemed to have resynched - I'll see if they stay around this time!

Answer (score 1):

When I choose one mail source - instead of the "combined view" - the folders menu option shows all the other folders. Guess the "combined view" shows only a smaller common (sub) folder list.

Answer (score 0):

what I did is to go to the Inbox, click the Option, then Folders, and click in the Inbox ICON (the folder drawing, NOT the Inbox WORD), and it showed the sub-folders.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the inbox and a drop down box will appear with all your folders

Comment: Some pictures would improve the answer somewhat

Answer (score 0):

You can click your inbox to show the folders and also change sync options by long pressing each folder in the default ICS mail client.

Comment: You answer would be more helpful if you are more descriptive.